# Android: NPE while loading Alertdialog with Gridview

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Hello and thanks for your help!

Upon clicking the button, the alertdialog should open up with a gridview inside.

**This is my code:**

```
    loginWith.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.loginWith));
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_loginwith, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_loginwith));
            builder.setView(layout);

            GridView gridView = (GridView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gvLoginwith);
            gridView.setAdapter(new LoginWithAlertDialogImageAdapter(context));
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            loginWithFacebook();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            loginWithGoogle();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            loginWithLinkedIn();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            loginWithTwitter();
                            break;
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

But it ends up leaving the NullPointerException at `gridView.setAdapter()` part above and the `context.getResources().getString()` methods in the following class.

```
public class LoginWithAlertDialogImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public LoginWithAlertDialogImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.categorycontent_log_in_with, null);
            convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.loginwith_title);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.loginwith_icon);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.icon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        holder.icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        holder.icon.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        holder.title.setText(items[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(icons[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;
    }

    private Integer[] icons = {
            R.drawable.ic_facebook,
            R.drawable.ic_google,
            R.drawable.ic_linkedin,
            R.drawable.ic_twitter
    };

    private String[] items = {
            context.getResources().getString(R.string.facebook),
            context.getResources().getString(R.string.google),
            context.getResources().getString(R.string.linkedin),
            context.getResources().getString(R.string.twitter)
    };
}
```

How should this be overcome?

**Added** I corrected the adapter code following the suggestion as follows.

```
public class LoginWithAlertDialogImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private String items[];

    public LoginWithAlertDialogImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        items = new String[] {
                context.getResources().getString(R.string.facebook),
                context.getResources().getString(R.string.google),
                context.getResources().getString(R.string.linkedin),
                context.getResources().getString(R.string.twitter)
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.categorycontent_log_in_with, null);
            convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.loginwith_title);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.loginwith_icon);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.icon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        holder.icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        holder.icon.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        holder.title.setText(items[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(icons[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;
    }

    private Integer[] icons = {
            R.drawable.ic_facebook,
            R.drawable.ic_google,
            R.drawable.ic_linkedin,
            R.drawable.ic_twitter
    };
}
```

Now the NullPointerException is not thrown anymore, but the thing is the icons and the icon titles and the GridView itself are not shown, but only the title of the AlertDialog is shown. Do you figure out the next issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.facebook)
```

`context` is `null` .

**Why?**

`items` Array is declared and initialized as a *class level variable*, during adding items in `items` Array, using `context` for accessing `getResources` method which is `null` because `context` is initialized inside constructor of `LoginWithAlertDialogImageAdapter` class.

Means `context` is accessed before executing constructor of `LoginWithAlertDialogImageAdapter` class.

So, to fix this issue declare `items` Array as class level variable but add item in it after initializing `context` :

```
private String[] items;
public LoginWithAlertDialogImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        ...
        items = {
            context.getResources().getString(R.string.facebook),
              ...
             };
    }
```

Comment: and possibly the same solution applies to the `Integer[] icons`, doesn't it?

Comment: @newbieprogrammer: No in case of `icons` Array not using context for accessing drawable ids, because `R.drawable.ic_facebook` is available statically inside `R` file so we can access it directly as currently you are doing

Comment: I edited the question, and can you review that also? I really appreciate it.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer : Dude,Change `@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length();
    }`